# Error saving excelPackage

Tags: c#, epplus

I am carrying a excel file with two WorkSheet, the first data to feed and the second WorkSheet containing a PivotTable. Insert data in the first WorkSheet and try to save throws exception.

Exception:
InneException {"The cachesource is not a worksheet"}
Message "Error saving file C:\Users\idias\Desktop\Modelo.xlsx"

```
using (FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog())
        {
            if (folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(@"C:\Users\idias\Desktop\teste\Modelo.xlsx");
                if (!fileInfo.Exists)
                    throw new Exception("Arquivo Modelo não encontrado");

                string filename = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath, fileInfo.Name);

                fileInfo.CopyTo(filename, true);

                fileInfo = new FileInfo(filename);

                using (ExcelPackage excelPackage = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
                {
                    ExcelWorkbook excelWorkBook = excelPackage.Workbook;

                    DataTable dtPlanoConta = Negocio.Financeiro.Relatorio.RecuperarPlanoConta();
                    if (dtPlanoConta.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        ExcelWorksheet excelWorksheet = excelWorkBook.Worksheets[1];
                        //Add some items in the cells...
                        int row = 3;
                        foreach (DataRow dr in dtPlanoConta.Rows)
                        {
                            row++;

                            //Campos                                        
                            excelWorksheet.SetValue(row, 1, dr["ID"]);
                            excelWorksheet.SetValue(row, 2, dr["FATHER_ID"]);
                            excelWorksheet.SetValue(row, 3, dr["DESCRICAO_FORMATADA"]);
                        }

                        row = 1;
                        for (int i = 0; i < dtPlanoConta.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            row++;

                            //Campos
                            excelWorksheet.Cells[row, 1].Style.Numberformat.Format = "@";
                            excelWorksheet.Cells[row, 2].Style.Numberformat.Format = "@";
                            excelWorksheet.Cells[row, 3].Style.Numberformat.Format = "@";
                        }

                        excelWorksheet.Cells[excelWorksheet.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();
                    }

                    DataTable dtDemonstrativo = Negocio.Financeiro.Relatorio.RecuperarDemonstrativo(1, 3, "2015");
                    if (dtDemonstrativo.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        ExcelWorksheet excelWorksheet = excelWorkBook.Worksheets[2];

                        //Add some items in the cells...
                        int row = 1;
                        foreach (DataRow dr in dtDemonstrativo.Rows)
                        {
                            row++;

                            //Campos                                        
                            excelWorksheet.Cells[row, 1].Value = dr["ID"];
                            excelWorksheet.Cells[row, 2].Value = dr["OPERACAO"];
                            excelWorksheet.Cells[row, 3].Value = dr["MES_ANO"];
                            excelWorksheet.Cells[row, 4].Value = dr["VALOR_PLANEJADO"];
                            excelWorksheet.Cells[row, 5].Value = dr["VALOR_REALIZADO"];
                            excelWorksheet.Cells[row, 6].Value = dr["DIFERENCA_REAIS"];
                            excelWorksheet.Cells[row, 7].Value = dr["DIFERENCA_PERCENTUAL"];
                        }

                        row = 1;
                        for (int i = 0; i < dtDemonstrativo.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            row++;

                            //Campos
                            excelWorksheet.Cells[row, 1].Style.Numberformat.Format = "@";
                            excelWorksheet.Cells[row, 2].Style.Numberformat.Format = "@";
                            excelWorksheet.Cells[row, 3].Style.Numberformat.Format = "DD/yyyy";
                            excelWorksheet.Cells[row, 3].Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,##0.000";
                            excelWorksheet.Cells[row, 4].Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,##0.000";
                            excelWorksheet.Cells[row, 5].Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,##0.000";
                            excelWorksheet.Cells[row, 6].Style.Numberformat.Format = "#,##0.000";
                        }

                        excelWorksheet.Cells[excelWorksheet.Dimension.Address].AutoFitColumns();
                    }

                    excelPackage.Save(); // This is the important part.
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add ExcelWorksheet to the ExcelWorkbook before writing to cells.
Take a look at [their samples](https://excelpackage.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Creating%20an%20Excel%20spreadsheet%20from%20scratch)

Comment: Hello Rui, thanks for the reply. I did what you suggested but still throwing the same error. I'm using a ready-made spreadsheet site (http://www.daxpatterns.com/parent-child-hierarchies/)

Answer (score 0):

Did a Google search for the error message, and saw some of the source code for ExcelPackage (you may see it [here](http://workspacesvn.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/product/Payment/packages/EPPlus3.0_Example/EPPlus/Table/PivotTable/ExcelPivotCacheDefinition.cs)) where the exception is thrown. It seems that if you modify source data for a pivot table, you might need to refresh/recreate the cache source. Check for the PivotTable inside your ExcelWorkSheet object - try to debug its values previous to saving the file